# The OLS Estimator of $\sigma^2$

Tags: least-squares, variance

I have a question regarding the OLS Estimator of $\sigma^2$. In Gujarati's book on Econometrics author derives $E(\sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_i^2)$ (aka the expected value of residuals) to be $(n-2)\sigma$. However, I can't understand how author calculates $E\sum_{i=1}^n (u_i -\bar u)^2$ to be equal to $(n-1)\sigma$ when for a PRL (population regression line) we assume by GM theorem that $\bar u$ should be equal to zero.

I do understand that $E(u_i|X)=0$ and it looks like Gujarati is talking about $E(u_i|Y)$ in that equation. But why then it makes difference if by default we assume that the mean value for the error term in the population should be equal to zero? Is there then any difference between $\bar u$ and $E(u)$?

Comment: I don't know everything that you're talking about, but I can tell you that if $X_i$ are $n$ independent identically distributed random variables with finite variance and $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ then $E \left [ \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2 \right ] = (n-1)\sigma^2$. By contrast if you replaced $\overline{X}$ by $E[X_i]$ then it would be $n \sigma^2$. This is the "Bessel correction". One way to understand it is to notice that $\overline{X}$ is slightly correlated with $X_i$ (the covariance is $-\frac{1}{n^2} \sigma^2$).

Comment: By contrast, $E[X_i]$ is a constant, so it is uncorrelated with $X_i$. So there is indeed a major difference between $\overline{X}$ and $E[X_i]$.

Comment: I still trying to get the idea as I did the calculations many times but I can't see how covariance of $\bar X$ and $X_i$ is equal to the one you have written? And I think this is a stumbling block for me. Can you describe it thoroughly and I will mark this question as solved then?

Comment: Which of the three pieces do you not understand at the moment?

Comment: You wrote "One way to understand it is to notice that $\bar X$ is slightly correlated with $X_i$ ..." <-- This piece. As I'm trying to step-by-step calculate the very equation but a) I don't see any $\sigma$ there - only $\mu$ b) I can't understand why $E(\bar X)$ should not be equal to $E(X_i)$ and should not be equal to $\mu$

Can you just please show how you derive the covariance?

Comment: $E[\overline{X}]=E[X_i]=\mu$ indeed, but there are squares in my calculation. Don't make the mistake of interchanging a nonlinear function with an expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be $n$ independent, identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Let $S'^2$ be the "unnormalized" estimator of the variance, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2$. Then $\mathbb{E}[S'^2]=(n-1)\sigma^2$. Proof:

$$\mathbb{E}[S'^2]=\mathbb{E} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu+\mu-\overline{X})^2 \\
= \mathbb{E} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2 + 2(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X}) + (\mu-\overline{X})^2 \right ) \\
= n \left ( \sigma^2 - \frac{2}{n} \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{n} \sigma^2 \right ) \\
= (n-1) \sigma^2.$$

For the first term this is just summing up $n$ copies of $\sigma^2$. In the second term, write:

$$\mathbb{E}[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\overline{X})]=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[(X_i-\mu)(\mu-X_j)].$$

The term $j=i$ contributes $-\sigma^2$ to the sum; the others contribute nothing because of independence.

In the last term, write $\mathbb{E}[(\mu-\overline{X})^2]=\mathbb{E} \left [ \left ( \mu-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right )^2 \right ]$. Use the multinomial theorem to expand the square. Cancel the cross terms using independence again, and then notice that you have $n$ copies of $\frac{1}{n^2} \sigma^2$ remaining. (There are shorter proofs of this: ultimately I am just using that variances of independent r.v.s add and $\operatorname{Var}(aX)=a^2 \operatorname{Var}(X)$ for constants $a$.)

I'm not sure exactly what is being calculated to obtain $(n-2)\sigma^2$.

Comment: Looks like I got the logic but could you please explain how you calculated $(\mu - \bar X)^2$ to be $(1/n)\sigma^2$. Shouldn't it be equal to zero?

Comment: @GenrikhLukianchuk The variance of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is $n \sigma^2$ by the independence; dividing by $n$ divides this variance by $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: I'm doing right the same but after expanding I get (concerning the 3rd equation):
$E(\mu^2 - (2\mu)/n*\sum_{i=1}^n X_i + 1/n^2*\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)$

Comment: You should find that you have $E \left [ \mu^2 - \frac{2}{n} \mu \sum_{i=1}^n X_i + \left ( \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right )^2 \right ]$. That last term needs the multinomial theorem to be evaluated.

Comment: But for the last term $1/n$ is just a constant, right? It should be behind brackets then being $1/n^2$. At the same time as we assume $X_i$ are i.i.d we can re-write the last term to $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i)^2$, correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes, my $1/n^2$ should be outside the brackets. And yes, *because* we have the expectation the cross terms cancel out and you are left with just $\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2]$ there.

Comment: Ok, and that's what I do:
$E(\mu^2) = \mu^2$; $E(-\mu*2/n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=(-2\mu/n)*n*\mu$
Looks like they do not cancel each other out as we are not left with $-\mu^2$

Comment: The first two terms of that expansion give you $-\mu^2$ but $E \left [ \left ( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right )^2 \right ]$ has a $\mu^2$ term in it to cancel that out.

Comment: I finally saw it! Thank you so much!